# Getting a slice from pandas dataframe by comparing contents of df1 with df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, for each `id` in `df1` I need to pick rows from `df2` with same `id`, filter out rows where `df2.ApplicationDate < df1.ApplicationDate` and count how many of such rows exist.

Here is how I am doing it currently:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    count = len(df2[(df2['PersonalId']==row['PersonalId']) 
                        & (df2['ApplicationDate'] < row['ApplicationDate']])
    counts.append(count)
```

This approach works but its hellishly slow on large dataframes, is there any way to accelerate it?

Edit: added sample input with expected output

```
df1:                  
   Id ApplicationDate
0   1         5-12-20
1   2         6-12-20
2   3         7-12-20
3   4         8-12-20
4   5         9-12-20
5   6        10-12-20
df2:
   Id ApplicationDate
0   1         4-11-20
1   1         4-12-20
2   3         5-12-20
3   3         8-12-20
4   5         1-12-20
```

expected `counts` for each id: `[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`

Comment: kindly share sample data with expected output

Comment: the count for `3` should be 2, right? something like this :``df1.merge(df2, on="Id", how="left").assign(
    temp=lambda x: x.ApplicationDate_y.notna()
).groupby("Id").temp.sum()``

Comment: @sammy, no, row with id `3` appers twice in second dataframe but only for one row is `df2.ApplicationDate` less than `df1.ApplicationDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1.merge(df2, on="Id", how="left").assign(
    temp=lambda x: x.ApplicationDate_y.notna(),
    tempr=lambda x: x.ApplicationDate_x > x.ApplicationDate_y,
    counter=lambda x: x.temp & x.tempr,
).groupby("Id").counter.sum()

Id
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    1
6    0
Name: counter, dtype: int64
```

The code above merges the dataframe and then uses the sum of the conditions based on the groupby to get the count.

Answer (score 3):

You can can left join both tables:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Id', how='left')
```

Result:

```
   Id ApplicationDate_x ApplicationDate_y
0   1        2020-05-12        2020-04-11
1   1        2020-05-12        2020-04-12
2   2        2020-06-12               NaT
3   3        2020-07-12        2020-05-12
4   3        2020-07-12        2020-08-12
5   4        2020-08-12               NaT
6   5        2020-09-12        2020-01-12
7   6        2020-10-12               NaT
```

Then you can compare dates, group by `'Id'` and count `True` values per group:

```
df3.ApplicationDate_x.gt(df3.ApplicationDate_y).groupby(df3.Id).sum()
```

Result:

```
Id
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    1
6    0
```